# How to add an array (list with 1 element) to a dataframe - python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a for loop which produces 5 different arrays for every iteration.
For example for one iteration:

```
a=[[1,datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 28, 0, 0)]]

b=[[5839,datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 28, 0, 0)]]

c=[[0.5,datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 28, 0, 0)]]

d=[[2.568,datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 28, 0, 0)]]

e=[[0.005,datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 28, 0, 0)]]
```

I am trying to create a pandas dataframe with columns:

```
df_cols = ['date', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Where the data from every iteration would populate each row:

| date | a | b | c | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28-May-21 | 1 | 5839 | 0.5 | 2.568 | 0.005 |
| 27-May-21 | (next iteration data) |  |  |  |  |

Tried to append all that data for each column to a separate array, using:

```
tmp_a.append(a)
tmp_b.append(b)
tmp_c.append(c)
tmp_d.append(d)
tmp_e.append(e)
```

But then I get 5 very weird arrays and the date is not in date format.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend transforming the 5 lists into a single list representing row data, and building a complete list of all rows to create the frame:

```
data = []
for a, b, c, d, e in generator():
    data.append([a[0][1], *[i[0] for lst in (a, b, c, d, e) for i in lst]])

df_cols = ['date', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=df_cols)
```

`data`:

```
[[datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 28, 0, 0), 1, 5839, 0.5, 2.568, 0.005]]
```

`df`:

```
        date  a     b    c      d      e
0 2021-05-28  1  5839  0.5  2.568  0.005
```

---

Complete code:

```
import datetime

import pandas as pd


def generator():  # Simulate list generation
    a = [[1, datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 28, 0, 0)]]
    b = [[5839, datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 28, 0, 0)]]
    c = [[0.5, datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 28, 0, 0)]]
    d = [[2.568, datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 28, 0, 0)]]
    e = [[0.005, datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 28, 0, 0)]]
    yield a, b, c, d, e


data = []
for a, b, c, d, e in generator():
    data.append([a[0][1], *[i[0] for lst in (a, b, c, d, e) for i in lst]])

df_cols = ['date', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=df_cols)

print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but I get list index out for range error because of a[0][1]. I tried a[0] but I still get the same error.

Comment: Okay that would imply that `a` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in the wrong format to pass it to a Dataframe (or any table for that matter). You are trying to produce a 1 dimensional row out of 2 dimensional data like so:

a_val date_val

b_val date_val

c_val date_val

d_val date_val

e_val date_val

You should make a list such as `[date_val, a_val, b_val, c_val, d_val, e_val]` instead or a dictionary like
`my_dict = {"date": date_val, "a": a_val, "b": b_val, ...}`